# Elementary OS Loki wifi will not connect 2018

Tags: release-loki, wifi, networking

I've got a fresh install of Elementary OS, and am unable to connect to wifi. Details below.

Elementary OS Version:

`uname -ra`

> Linux waynes-world 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Wireless Card: 
[Intel AC 9260](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/wireless/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-9260.html)

`sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 29
   serial: 74:e5:f9:cb:d8:c9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=33.610294.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:dd300000-dd303fff
```

I've install the firmware from here:
[Firmware](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi)

Restarted NetworkManager:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Wifi still unable to connect.

dmesg output:

```
    [    4.935449] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
    [    5.123798] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
    [    5.320809] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
    [    5.383457] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
    [   70.429230] wlo1: authenticate with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f
    [   70.437808] wlo1: send auth to f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (try 1/3)
    [   70.477826] wlo1: authenticated
    [   70.480058] wlo1: associate with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (try 1/3)
    [   70.487897] wlo1: RX AssocResp from f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (capab=0x1111 status=0 aid=3)
    [   70.489798] wlo1: associated
    [   70.489863] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
    [   70.556263] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f
    [  116.045739] wlo1: deauthenticating from f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    [  116.055823] wlo1: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
```

LOGS:

cat /var/log/syslog

.....

```
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9260] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'Dragon Age' (dc0b99c7-9229-4b93-9a73-fa2b1b55a7ab)
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9264] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="dc0b99c7-9229-4b93-9a73-fa2b1b55a7ab" name="Dragon Age" pid=1486 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9268] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9271] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9284] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9289] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Dragon Age' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9290] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9411] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9434] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9442] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Dragon Age' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9443] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Dragon Age'
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9444] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9445] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9445] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9446] Config: added 'psk' value ''
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9615] sup-iface[0x979f90,wlo1]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Mar 31 16:58:38 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529918.9768] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world wpa_supplicant[1018]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (SSID='Dragon Age' freq=5745 MHz)
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.256149] wlo1: authenticate with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.263263] wlo1: send auth to f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (try 1/3)
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world wpa_supplicant[1018]: wlo1: Trying to associate with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (SSID='Dragon Age' freq=5745 MHz)
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.266260] wlo1: authenticated
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.268035] wlo1: associate with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (try 1/3)
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.271759] wlo1: RX AssocResp from f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f (capab=0x1111 status=0 aid=3)
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6021] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world wpa_supplicant[1018]: wlo1: Associated with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.273585] wlo1: associated
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6105] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world wpa_supplicant[1018]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world wpa_supplicant[1018]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f completed [id=0 id_str=]
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6179] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6212] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6212] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Dragon Age'.
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6213] device (wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6217] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529921.6236] dhcp4 (wlo1): dhclient started with pid 1957
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world gnome-session[1198]: (nm-applet:1471): nm-applet-CRITICAL **: get_menu_item_for_ap: assertion 'dup_data.hash != NULL' failed
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world kernel: [  273.316744] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world gnome-session[1198]: message repeated 4 times: [ (nm-applet:1471): nm-applet-CRITICAL **: get_menu_item_for_ap: assertion 'dup_data.hash != NULL' failed]
Mar 31 16:58:41 waynes-world dhclient[1957]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x278f93e)
Mar 31 16:58:43 waynes-world avahi-daemon[851]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::3e11:2f8d:5b45:2b70.
Mar 31 16:58:43 waynes-world avahi-daemon[851]: New relevant interface wlo1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar 31 16:58:43 waynes-world avahi-daemon[851]: Registering new address record for fe80::3e11:2f8d:5b45:2b70 on wlo1.*.
Mar 31 16:58:45 waynes-world dhclient[1957]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x278f93e)
Mar 31 16:58:52 waynes-world dhclient[1957]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x278f93e)
Mar 31 16:59:04 waynes-world dhclient[1957]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x278f93e)
Mar 31 16:59:23 waynes-world dhclient[1957]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x278f93e)
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3339] dhcp4 (wlo1): request timed out
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3341] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> timeout
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3666] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1957
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3667] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed timeout -> done
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3673] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3675] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3686] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'Dragon Age'
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3695] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world avahi-daemon[851]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3e11:2f8d:5b45:2b70 on wlo1.
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world avahi-daemon[851]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::3e11:2f8d:5b45:2b70.
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world avahi-daemon[851]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world kernel: [  319.045353] wlo1: deauthenticating from f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world kernel: [  319.057913] wlo1: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world wpa_supplicant[1018]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f4:f5:e8:72:9a:2f reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3887] sup-iface[0x979f90,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Mar 31 16:59:27 waynes-world NetworkManager[853]:   [1522529967.3888] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 31 16:59:30 waynes-world gnome-session[1198]: (nm-applet:1471): libnm-WARNING **: (nm-access-point.c:285):nm_access_point_connection_valid: runtime check failed: (ap_ssid != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

please type `rfkill list`
you may see somethings like

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

if you got some `blocked: yes`  try `rfkill unblock all`

if you got more then one wireless LAN

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes​
```

try to blacklist one of them, see 
https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/wireless-problem.2316/

`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

add `blacklist acer_wmi` as a new line at the bottom of this file.

then reboot.

Or if you like one-line:

`echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf​`

Comment: Thank you. But this solution did not work.  I switched to Ubuntu 18.04, and everything seems to be working.